# Dynamically increase iterations for PBKDF2 when the password is wrong

Tags: php, laravel-5, pbkdf2, password-hash

I am thinking about implementing PBKDF2 in my Laravel 5 app to replace the default blowfish-based authentication.

Is it feasible to double the iteration count each time the password has been entered incorrectly?

e.g. Default iterations are 2000, and when the password is wrong the first time, the next attempt will be 4000 iterations, then 8000, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't work. Use a throttle mechanic instead. – You'd want to potentially reset this at some point, and you don't know the original value. Sounds like a potential DoS waiting to happen.

Comment: If you had 3 (or 5 or 10) wrong login attempts, you could simply stop accepting credentials for that username for 10 minutes (or 30 or 2 hours).

Comment: @ArtjomB. That's a much better idea, don't know why I didn't think of something like that or just simply lock the account after X failed logins. +1

Comment: I would not stop accepting logins for longer than 1 minute, otherwise an attacker can lock out a user easily. Even a waiting period of some seconds will thwart any online brute-force attempts.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Then perhaps an additive delay for each failed login attempt up to a maximum?

Comment: @imperium2335 - That's what i would do, yes.

Answer (score 3):

While you could continue iterating on the PBKDF2 hash in theory, it's made impossible by the fact that you don't know the original value, which is why you have a hash in the first place. You could store the iteration count and try resuming the iteration, but you'd hit a snag — not having knowledge of the key-derivation function's internal state.

Consider the following:

```
var_dump(($hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", "password", "salt", 2000)));
var_dump(hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $hash, "salt", 2000));
var_dump(hash_pbkdf2("sha256", "password", "salt", 4000));
```

This produces:

```
string(64) "9209a0c90243e88b89488f99cd7ea010c244cc7a9d4bf65c157f2d8f642eb952"
string(64) "b90c5d9a2d8bb559a36682bd6044a8da0480199148339fe34ef62598e052b0b6"
string(64) "99a4d4dd66f714fae1bab9246ea449dd598d7683a569227c07cdb679e3ed3474"
```

Ergo, this is impossible. And also a denial of service waiting to happen if it *did* work, as it would be your server doing the computations.

In short, stick with `password_hash` (which Laravel uses) that does all of the security for you. The less you do to your auth code, the less you can introduce a vulnerability.